# Trying to Read and then Log data from firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query documents from a collections and log them to the terminal. I keep getting the error FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore
This is my code:

```
import { collection} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {db} from '../../firebase/firestore';
 useEffect(() => {
     const max = collection(db,'UsersData')
     .where('Reps','==',4)
     .get()
     .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
            console.log('User ID: ', documentSnapshot.data());
          });
     });
    
     return () => max();
   }, []);
```

I have tried adding firestore() before collection like it appears on the docs but still receive same error:

```
 useEffect(() => {
     const max = firestore()
     .collection(db,'UsersData')
     .where('Reps','==',4)
     .get()
     .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
            console.log('User ID: ', documentSnapshot.data());
          });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the name of the collection instead of the entire `db` object.  
You can try this code below:

```
import { collection } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../../firebase/firestore';

useEffect(() => {
  const max = collection(db, 'UsersData')
    .where('Reps', '==', 4)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
        console.log('User ID: ', documentSnapshot.data());
      });
    });

  return () => max();
}, []);
```

You don't need to add `firestore()` before `collection()` because `collection()` is already an exported function from the Firestore module.

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't solve my error